# Wordpress wp_head() Auto read CSS issue

Tags: wordpress

I have added `wp_head()` to head part because plugins require that but when I update any part of the blog in `wp-admin` blog it automatically adds following new `css` part inside `head`

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
```

When I delete path cookies it disappears. Why this happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the admin bar. You can remove it if you wish. In your functions.php, place:

```
show_admin_bar(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually that is  being added for the `admin bar`, to remove the `style` from the head you can paste this inside your `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

but above line will also remove the `admin bar` from the front end when you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to remove that white space (it's not caused by the admin bar) is to search out this css in style.css:

```
#page {
margin: 2em auto;
max-width: 1000px;
}
```

and switch the `2em` to `0em` or some variation of the same. That will remove the white space.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the admin bar, you have to add a call to wp_footer in footer section to fix this

```
<?php wp_footer();?>
```